Detect volume changes
Does anyone know a way to detect volume changes in SwiftUI? I’m trying to disable the OK button if the volume is not set to maximum. The problem is that my app is a Signal Generator, and it requires the volume to be set to maximum in order to generate the required frequency. If the volume is set to 50%, which is the default sometimes, it won’t work. I have added an alert, but I want to enforce this somehow. I’ve also added a slider to make it easier for users, but I’m not sure if that’s enough
PS: The SliderView won't work in the simulator, requires a real device to show up
import SwiftUI
import MediaPlayer

struct VolumeAlertView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Binding var hasShown: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundStyle(Color(.systemGray6))
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack(spacing: 24) {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Image(systemName: "speaker.wave.3.fill")
                        .font(.system(size: 50))
                        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                    
                    Text("Volume")
                        .font(.title2.bold())
                    
                    Text("You must set your device volume to maximum.")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                       
                }
                
                VolumeSliderView()
                    .frame(height: 40)
                    .padding()
                
                Button("OK") {
                    isPresented = false
                    hasShown = true
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .controlSize(.extraLarge)
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color(.systemGray6))
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}

struct VolumeSliderView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MPVolumeView {
        let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
        volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = true
        volumeView.tintColor = .systemBlue
        return volumeView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MPVolumeView, context: Context) {
        // No update needed
    }
}

#Preview {
    VolumeSliderView()
}

the above i have tried

it can't be adjusted manually. Apple has it own safety reasons to prevent that

Could you use NotificationCenter observers? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1415360-addobserver


let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleVolumeChange(_:)), name: AVAudioSession.volumeChangedNotificationName, object: nil)



Then handle your logic to pop-up the alert for changing volume in another function handleVolumeChange

Oh cool. I have managed to make it work with the audioSession. Thank you chief
